# Is there an Eclipse new Project Wizard for Java EE 6 Web Profile Applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am using Eclipse 3.7 Java EE (more correct STS 2.8) with Oracle GlassFish Server Tools, and I am looking for an Project wizard to create an new Java EE 6 Web Profile project. I only find wizards for EARs on the one side and wizards for Servlet projects on other, but not for the Java EE 6 Web Profile.

Of course I can use Maven template, but I would expect that there is an Eclipse wizard without Maven.

*May I am only to blind to find it. - so forgive me if it is a silly question, but I have really tried to figure it out by myself*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am only interessted in testing some JSF 2.0 Stuff this works for me:

- New Project with `Dynamic Web Project` wizard
- Change Configuration to: `Java Server Faces 2.0 Project`
- change JSF Implementation Library on wizard Page "JSF Capabilities" to `Disable Library Configuration`